# Raspberry pi cold wallet safety

Tags: cold-storage, raspberry-pi

I don't have an old computer to make an air gap. I do have a raspberry pi from 2012 though. If I made a new SD card with fresh OS would this be safe enough to make cold wallets on? It would be easy to hide, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!
Boot the Raspberry, change admin password (keep this safe!) turn off the wifi and bluetooth.

Turn wifi and bluetooth off:

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt`

Reboot and NEVER turn on the internet again on this Raspberry.

Note all the software you think you will need (Monero, gpg and maybe KeePassX). Download them on your online mac/pc, checksum all the files and signatures, move to usb stick. Plug into Raspberry and checksum again all the files. 
Install what you need, store your password for the Monero Wallet in KeePassX (maybe also use an extra usb-stick as a KeePassX-keyfile).

Some more information on making a cold wallet and a view-only wallet on your online machine to check the balance:

[Monero, how to create a view-only wallet and verify cold wallet's balance - Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=actU0Kzh8b4)

[Setup view only wallet and check balance - Reddit topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7eim2d/okay_so_paper_wallet_made_test_send_sent_view/?st=jac9gjll&sh=50cfe531)

Comment: Luckily no internet hardware on those old Pi's. Can you add a thought on how to safely make sure you have a fresh OS on Pi? The only way I know how to flash an OS to SD card is to do it on an internet connection computer...

Comment: I'm not sure how to securely do that. Other than downloading the image file, checksum and signature, turn off the internet and use safe software to load it up on the SD card. 
If you want you can find me on [Keybase](https://keybase.io/toldenburger), I have a folder with verified software anyone can use. (If they trust me)
I also have a raspbian iso there also.

Comment: Seems like safest way to generate cold wallet is with dice/coin, and just use Rpi for translating to address/mnemonics. I wish cli/gui had coin/dice input translation

Comment: If you use an offline version of [MoneroWalletGenerator](https://moneroaddress.org) you can do just that. I then used the View Key on my online machine with a view only wallet to keep an eye on that account.